# Generic merge sort in C++ using a user-defined comparison function or the < operator by default

Tags: c++, sorting, c++14, template, mergesort

I wanted to implement a generic merge sort algorithm using the same interface as `std::sort()`. The interface takes first and last iterators to a range of elements in any container. The user has the option to provide a custom function that compares two elements; if none is provided, the operator `<` is used by default.

I handled the default case by creating a wrapper function that calls the real function using a lambda expression, but I'm wondering if there's a way to get rid of this second wrapper function.

Feedback on any aspect of the code is welcome.

```
template <class RandomAccessIterator, class Compare>
void mergesort(RandomAccessIterator first, RandomAccessIterator last, Compare comp)
{
    size_t n = last - first;

    if (n <= 1)
        return;

    size_t m = n / 2;

    mergesort(first, first + m, comp);
    mergesort(first + m, last, comp);

    std::vector<RandomAccessIterator::value_type> v(last - first);
    RandomAccessIterator itResult = v.begin();

    RandomAccessIterator itLower = first;
    RandomAccessIterator itUpper = first + m;

    while (itLower != first + m && itUpper != last)
        *(itResult++) = comp(*itLower, *itUpper) ? *(itLower++) : *(itUpper++);

    if (itUpper == last)
        std::copy(itLower, first + m, itResult);
    else
        std::copy(itUpper, last, itResult);

    std::copy(v.begin(), v.end(), first);
}

template <class RandomAccessIterator>
void mergesort(RandomAccessIterator first, RandomAccessIterator last)
{
    mergesort(first, last, [](RandomAccessIterator::value_type a, RandomAccessIterator::value_type b) { return a < b; });
}
```

Comment: [This may be an interesting read](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24650627/1896169)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Avoid a copy by passing by const reference.

```
[](RandomAccessIterator::value_type const& a, RandomAccessIterator::value_type const& b) { return a < b; }
                                    ^^^^^^                                     ^^^^^^
```

Don't need an if statatement here:

```
if (itUpper == last)
    std::copy(itLower, first + m, itResult);
else
    std::copy(itUpper, last, itResult);
```

One of these ranges will be empty and just do nothing.

```
std::copy(itLower, first + m, itResult);
std::copy(itUpper, last, itResult);
```

To avoid a copy (which can be expensive on non POD types). Prefer to use move.

```
std::move(itLower, first + m, itResult);
std::move(itUpper, last, itResult);

std::move(v.begin(), v.end(), first);
```

You spend a lot of time creating the temporary array:

```
std::vector<RandomAccessIterator::value_type> v(last - first);
```

Basically this causes calls to new for every call to `void mergesort(RandomAccessIterator first, RandomAccessIterator last, Compare comp)`. You can optimize this by allocating the temp space once in `void mergesort(RandomAccessIterator first, RandomAccessIterator last)` and pass the section of the temp array that recursive function can use.

I know you are trying to be explicit with `RandomAccessIterator`. But it is more traditional to use single letter for template types. Also there is no compiler validation that your iterator is random accesses (so you are giving a false sense of security to your user).

C++20 should add `Concepts` (finally). Single letter template types will work well with this.

```
 template<typename I>
 requires RandomAccessIterator<I>
 void mergesort(I begin, I end){}
```

For C++ pre 20 You can write:

```
 template<typename I>
 // requires RandomAccessIterator<I>
 void mergesort(I begin, I end){}
```

Which provides the same information and when concepts are added you can just remove the comment.

Comment: Will there be any predefined concepts in the library? Otherwise, people would need to reinvent them.

Comment: @Incomputable [RandomAccessIterator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/RandomAccessIterator) and [friends](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept)

Comment: @Snowhawk, I guess I should’ve written Concepts, e.g. the new language feature. Sorry for not making it clear. At the moment, cppreference has only ranges prototype.

Comment: The Concepts TS does not specify any concept definitions. The goal for the Concepts TS was to ship a language extension, not provide library support. The committee didn't want to lock the language down to the current iteration of Concepts so they opted not to provide a concept definition library.  Hopefully a library extension for Concept definitions is proposed/standardized once they address their immediate concerns. I just hope they can deliver on the *abbreviated function template* syntax.

Comment: @Snowhawk, I've never heard of the latter term. [This paper](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2017/p0696r0.html) proposes removing them though.

Answer (score 6):

> ```
> template <class RandomAccessIterator>
> void mergesort(RandomAccessIterator first, RandomAccessIterator last)
> {
>     mergesort(first, last, [](RandomAccessIterator::value_type a, RandomAccessIterator::value_type b) { return a < b; });
> }
> ```

`RandomAccessIterator::value_type` prevents using this function for types such as simple C arrays, or even vectors if the vector uses a pointer as its iterator. Prefer `typename std::iterator_traits<RandomAccessIterator>::value_type`. I find that that's a mouthful, so I tend to use `auto`:

```
// since C++14, you can use `auto` as parameters to a lambda
[](auto const& a, auto const& b) { return a < b; }
```

Also, rather than comparing `a < b`, you should use `std::less`. Note that it is a functor, so you don't need to wrap it in a lambda:

```
mergesort(first, last, std::less<>{});
```

Note also that [pointers need to be compared using `std::less<T*>`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21079958/1896169), so you should probably specify the value type (`std::less<>` compares using `<`):

```
mergesort(first, last, std::less<typename std::iterator_traits<RandomAccessIterator>::value_type>{});
```

---

> ```
> mergesort(first, first + m, comp);
> mergesort(first + m, last, comp);
>
> std::vector<RandomAccessIterator::value_type> v(last - first);
> RandomAccessIterator itResult = v.begin();
>
> RandomAccessIterator itLower = first;
> RandomAccessIterator itUpper = first + m;
>
> while (itLower != first + m && itUpper != last)
>     *(itResult++) = comp(*itLower, *itUpper) ? *(itLower++) : *(itUpper++);
>
> if (itUpper == last)
>     std::copy(itLower, first + m, itResult);
> else
>     std::copy(itUpper, last, itResult);
>
> std::copy(v.begin(), v.end(), first);
> ```

If you are willing to use standard algorithms, as it seems, you can use [`std::inplace_merge`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/inplace_merge):

```
mergesort(first, first + m, comp);
mergesort(first + m, last, comp);

std::inplace_merge(first, first + m, last, comp);
```

This will allocate memory each time you call it, so it's not as efficient as preallocating the buffer as [Loki Astari suggested](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/178974/49895), but if you wanted to take Loki's suggestion, it may be desirable to factor out the merging into a function that behaves similarly.

---

You can reduce the requirements on your iterator. You declare that you want a `RandomAccessIterator`, but you really don't need that. Just use `std::next` and `std::distance`:

```
auto n = std::distance(first, last);

if (n <= 1)
    return;

auto middle = std::next(first, n / 2);

mergesort(first, middle, comp);
mergesort(middle, last, comp);

...
```

`std::inplace_merge` requires that its iterators are Bidirectional Iterators, so that could be your requirement. Do note that a different iterator class *may* have a different algorithmic complexity, so you'd have to evaluate if there was any change.

Answer (score 4):

Just a small bit to add to the already great answers:

## Correctness

```
RandomAccessIterator itResult = v.begin();
```

This line is not correct. An iterator over a vector might still be a random access iterator, but it very likely won't be of the same iterator type as the iterators passed in (e.g. iterators over a `std::deque` or a custom container).

If insisting on proper static typing, this could be remedied as follows:

```
std::vector<RandomAccessIterator::value_type>::iterator itResult = v.begin();
// maybe introduce a type alias?
```

However, there's a much simpler and more maintainable choice: Just let the type be deduced!

```
auto itResult = v.begin();
```

More material on the topic: [CppCon 2014 Talk](https://youtu.be/xnqTKD8uD64?t=28m23s), [GotW discussion](https://herbsutter.com/2013/08/12/gotw-94-solution-aaa-style-almost-always-auto/), both by Herb Sutter.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my updated version after implementing all the comments received. It runs around 50% slower than `std::sort` for 1,000,000 randomly-generated integers, which doesn't seem too bad for a simple algorithm (`std::sort` is a [hybrid algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Introsort)).

```
template <typename I, typename Compare>
void mergesortInternal(const I first, const I last, const Compare comp, 
    const typename std::vector<typename I::value_type>::iterator firstMerge)
{
    const size_t n = last - first;

    if (n <= 1)
        return;

    const size_t m = n / 2;

    mergesortInternal(first, first + m, comp, firstMerge);
    mergesortInternal(first + m, last, comp, firstMerge);

    auto merge = firstMerge;

    I lower = first;
    I upper = first + m;

    while (lower != first + m && upper != last)
        *(merge++) = comp(*lower, *upper) ? *(lower++) : *(upper++);

    std::move(lower, first + m, merge);
    std::move(upper, last, merge);

    std::move(firstMerge, firstMerge + n, first);
}

template <typename I, typename Compare = std::less<I::value_type>>
void mergesort(const I first, const I last, const Compare comp = Compare())
{
    std::vector<I::value_type> mergeSpace(last - first);

    mergesortInternal(first, last, comp, mergeSpace.begin());
}
```

Comment: A fairer comparison would be with `std::stable_sort`, as mergesort is a stable sorting algorithm

Comment: @Justin Then it's only ~ 25% slower :-) Thanks!